# How to Remove Widgets in Reverse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have a scroll bug so i want to try Remove Widgets in Reverse.

**KV Example:**

```
BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, 0.80
                    ScrollView:
                        id: sv_underover      
                        GridLayout:                            
                            id: gridsonuc
                            cols: 1
                            spacing: '50dp'
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height
```

**Adding Widgets in PY Code:**

```
self.ids.gridsonuc.add_widget(box)
```

**Removing Widgets:**

```
def clear_widgets(self, *args):

        if self.ids.gridsonuc.children:            
            for child in [child for child in self.ids.gridsonuc.children]:
                self.ids.gridsonuc.remove_widget(child)
```

I think if we look at def clear_widgets(self, *args):, it removes widget in forward. I mean it removes widgets from starting firstly created to lastly created (up to down). I want to remove widgets from starting lastly created to firstly created (down to up)!

How can i do that? What should be the right code for def clear_widgets(self, *args)
Thanks very much

**What i tried and did not worked:**

```
def clear_widgets(self, *args):

        if self.ids.gridsonuc.children:            
            for child in [child for child in self.ids.gridsonuc.children][-1:]:
                self.ids.gridsonuc.remove_widget(child)
```

I put

```
[-1:]
```

But not worked.

Thanks very much

Comment: Did you mean to use `[child for child in self.ids.gridsonuc.children[-1:]]`? The slicing operator isn't following the proper syntax.

Comment: `for child in [child for child in self.ids.gridsonuc.children][-1:]:` has no syntax error according Vscode, program works but i does not clear widgets.
I also tried `[child for child in self.ids.gridsonuc.children[-1:]]:` but now worked as well.

Sorry for my poor english but i don't exactly understood 'The slicing operator isn't following the proper syntax'

Comment: You want to reverse the children of `self.ids.gridsonuc` so that will be `self.ids.gridsonuc.children[-1:]` or even better `reversed(self.ids.gridsonuc.children)`. Also you can probably write `for child in reversed(self.ids.gridsonuc.children):` and simplify the loop